# QProgressDialog doesn't display well

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, qprogressbar

I have some issues with the QProgressDialog class from the PySide2 lib : The progress bar doesn't display well for the first 2 steps.

My code is organised as below :

main.py

```
def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MainWindow()

   window.show()            
   app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Graphic.py

```
class ProgressBar:
   def __init__(self, SIZE):
       self.progress = QProgressDialog('Work in progress...', 'Cancel', 0, SIZE)
       self.progress.setAutoReset(True)
       self.progress.setAutoClose(True)
       self.progress.setMinimum(0)
       self.progress.setMaximum(size)
       self.progress.setFixedSize(250,100)
       self.progress.setWindowTitle("MyTitle")
       self.progress.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
       self.progress.show()
       self.progress.setValue(0)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       QMainWindow.__init__(self)

   def createProgressBar(self, SIZE):
       self.progressBar = ProgressBar(SIZE)

   def createClassA(self)
       ClassA = ClassA(self)
       ClassA.beautifulfunction(10)
```

ClassA.py

```
class ClassA:
   def __init__(self, parent):
      self.parent = parent

   def beautifulfunction(self, SIZE):
      self.parent.createProgressBar(SIZE)
      for index in range(0, SIZE):
         SOME CODE..
         self.parent.progressBar.progress.setValue(index + 1)
```

My next try will be to use threads but before I want to be sure that I can't fix my code without it.

Can you help ? Can you tell me why the first 2 steps of my progress bar doesn't display ?

Comment: provide a real [mre]

Comment: Try to add 'QtCore.qApp.processEvents()' inside of loop.